# When to call Interstitial Ad?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I am very confused on what event i should trigger the Interstitial Ad, or what is the best event to launch Interstitial Ad.

I tried the following:

```
onStart()

onDestroy()

onStop()

onResume()
```

Please help

Comment: Whom so ever has given me a down, if you have an answer, please reply and i can see what knowledge you have....

Comment: May be this may help https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en . As they it should be used in some transition points like if App is game you should show when it ends etc.

Comment: That was very informative, can you please suggest the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the instance of your ad in the class itself. Load the ad in OnCreate and the show the ad whenever you want it to be, some level change or OnPause, Ondestroy anytime you like.